# uploading and retrieving image from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am using firebase to upload a photo of a user into the database, I use expo image picker in combination, and here is the code:

```
    const handleImagePicked = async (pickerResult) => {
        console.log("here");
        if (!pickerResult.cancelled) {
          setImage(pickerResult.uri);
          const result = await uploadImageAsync(pickerResult.uri);
          if (result) {
            console.log("success");
            return;
          }
          alert("Upload failed, sorry :(");
        }
      };
    
      async function uploadImageAsync(uri) {
        const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onload = function () {
            resolve(xhr.response);
          };
          xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
          };
          xhr.responseType = "blob";
          xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
          xhr.send(null);
        });
    
  const ref = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(uid)
      .child("/profile_pictures/" + uid);

    
        const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);
   
        blob.close();
   
        const userRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
        const res = await userRef.update({ photo: snapshot });
        return await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      }
```

this works correctly and I am able to see in my firebase under storage a new folder is created and inside the there is the image users have uploaded.

to retrieve the image on a different screen this is what I do:

```
let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref(userId);
    imageRef
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then((url) => {
        setImage({ profileImageUrl: url });
      })
      .catch((e) =>
        console.log("getting downloadURL of image error => ", e)
      );
```

but however, when I visit my profile page it doesn't show the image since it tells me there is an error:

> getting downloadURL of image error =>  [FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'userId' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)]

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that no file exists in the location you call `getDownloadURL` on. From looking at the code, that makes sense.

You upload the image to:

```
firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(uid)
      .child("/profile_pictures/" + uid);
```

You try to get the download URL from:

```
firebase.storage().ref(userId);
```

Those are two different locations. The first points to `/$uid/profile_pictures/$uid`, while the second just points to `/$uid`. You should use a reference to the same path in both places, and my recommendation would be to use for both:

```
firebase
      .storage()
      .ref("/profile_pictures/" + uid);
```

Comment: thank you, I was looking at the wrong location, thanks again, but why not using the child again?

Comment: You can do the same with `child` if you want. There won't be any difference.